# javadoc:aggregate deletes product target folder

Tags: eclipse-rcp, maven-3, tycho, maven-javadoc-plugin

I can "mvn clean install" to generate zip file of my multi-project application in target folder of my product project. I can run "mvn clean javadoc:aggregate" to generate javadocs. 
no problem up to generating both...

When I run "mvn clean install javadoc:aggregate" javadoc is created but product zip is created and deleted.

I have tried to run mvn again but:

- "mvn clean install" generates product but deletes my javadoc target folder
- "mvn clean javadoc:aggregate" generates javadocs but deletes my product target folder.

What could be the reason? Any workaround?

Comment: How about `mvn clean install javadoc:aggregate` ?

Comment: Thanks Raghuram, tried that too :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in eclipse-repository that has shown up repeatedly on mailing lists etc. but there is no bug report for this yet. If you have a small, standalone example project to reproduce the problem, please [file a bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Tycho) and attach the project.

Comment: In the meanwhile, there has been a bug report related to this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=399756